# NFS CREATE File (overwrite) = zero size?

Tags: rpc, nfs, rfc

Im implementing NFS and almoste done but the [RFC section 3.3.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1813#section-3.3.8) says this in its description:

> mode
> One of UNCHECKED, GUARDED, and EXCLUSIVE. **UNCHECKED
> means that the file should be created without checking
> for the existence of a duplicate file in the same
> directory. In this case, how.obj_attributes is a sattr3
> describing the initial attributes for the file.** GUARDED
> specifies that the server should check for the presence
> of a duplicate file before performing the create and
> should fail the request with NFS3ERR_EXIST if a
> duplicate file exists. If the file does not exist, the
> request is performed as described for UNCHECKED.
> EXCLUSIVE specifies that the server is to follow
> exclusive creation semantics, using the verifier to
> ensure exclusive creation of the target. No attributes
> may be provided in this case, since the server may use
> the target file metadata to store the createverf3
> verifier.

so the question if UNCHECKED is the mode should i just set the length of the file to Zero or should i let the file be as it is? and if its a directory should i remove all the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the idea of `CREATE` with `UNCHECKED` is to apply the semantics of good old Unix system call `creat` -- so, truncation of a file's existing contents (if any) is implied. However I cannot find this specified all that clearly in the docs (!).

Trying to `CREATE` an existing *directory* is an error in any case -- there's a separate `MKDIR` for that (in NFS 3, the same applies to special files, with `MKNOD` -- `CREATE` is now for regular, normal, plain good old *files* only!-)